# GoogleJsonResponseException: API call to calendar.events.insert failed with error: Calendar usage limits exceeded

Tags: google-calendar-api

I have a personal project where I use the Google Calendar API in a Google Apps Script to iterate through my work schedule (reported via ICS feed as all day calendar events) and use it to insert actual calendar entries that block appropriate parts of my day.

Anyway, the script ran great for a while but now I am getting an very frustating "Calendar usage limits exceeded." error. I opened a Google Cloud Platform account and linked the Google Apps Script into a cloud project. Per that dashboard, I am not getting anywhere near my quota. So applying for an increase in the quota will probably do nothing, but I did it anyway.

I've looked at a number of prior Stack Overflow questions/responses and a few points of information so I don't get flamed:

- I am only accessing / deleting / creating a small number of events (call it 50-100; 2-3 months worth of shifts, and not every day has an entry). I also do some deletions, so the number of API calls is about 200 calls occurring over the span of 3-5 minutes (i.e. well under the quota.)
- No guests on the calendar entries or emails generated
- No new calendars
- No sharing of calendars
- I already have some delays hardcoded to prevent previously encountered Rate Exceeded errors, presumably from stepping through the calendars very rapidly. Frustratingly, if I insert longer delays, I run into the execution time limit on Google Apps Scripts of ~5 minutes and am hosed that way instead.
- I run this code manually about once per month, when new schedules are released. (So it is not something that occurs everyday, but it does occur now every time I run the code.)

I contacted Google tech support and was advised to post here, as the handy dandy Google Tech Team monitors this channel and will be *on the case*. Not really holding my breath, but I'm willing to be pleasantly surprised.

HALP!

Edit: I use the below function to insert the events. The all day events used ('spinevent') comes from an ICS feed generated by a medical scheduling software platform called SpinFusion.

```
 function createEvent(spinevent,hourStart,length,Title,TagforCreatedinPrimary,calendarId) {
  var start = getRelativeDate(spinevent, hourStart);
  var end = getRelativeDate(spinevent, hourStart + length);
  var newevent = {
    summary: Title + ' (' + TagforCreatedinPrimary + ',' + spinevent.summary.toString() + ')',
    location: 'Seattle Children\'s OR',
    description: TagforCreatedinPrimary,
    start: {
      dateTime: start.toISOString()
    },
    end: {
      dateTime: end.toISOString()
    }
  };
  Utilities.sleep(100);
  calcountattempts++;
  Logger.log("Att: "  + calcountattempts);
  if(calcountattempts >= calcounttostart){
    neweventID = Calendar.Events.insert(newevent, calendarId);
    calcountdone++;
    Logger.log("Done: "  + calcountdone);
  }
  Logger.log('Event ID: ' + neweventID.id);
}
```

Comment: Can you share your API interaction code? Does this error occur every day? How many API calls did you make the day you got the `Calendar usage limits exceeded error` and in what time frame?

Comment: See edits above.